# Authentication to mapped Samba shares failing after AD username change in Win7

Tags: windows-7, samba, file-sharing

**Background:** One of our users was recently married and changed her name. Correspondingly, we changed her AD username from *jane.doe* to *jane.smith*. However, she now cannot authenticate into any of our Samba shares, which use AD for authentication. Any attempt to access them (as mapped drives on her Windows 7 machine) results in a "user not found" error. However, logging in from a different host allows her to access all the drives just fine.

**The Problem:** Since the issue is clearly client-side, I am assuming that Windows has cached some old credentials with the pre-marriage username, which it is trying to use to authenticate to the file shares. This leads me to two problems:

1. How would I clear such a cache and force Windows to use the updated credentials?
2. How can this be addressed proactively so that any future name changes don't incur the same trouble?

**Additional Details:** The clients/workstations all run Windows 7 Pro. All relevant credentials belong to our AD domain, which is a Win 2k8 domain. The file shares are used with Samba 4.1.6 on an Ubuntu box. The Samba server is just a member server for file sharing.

Comment: Have you checked Credential Manager in Control Panel on the affected client machine?

Comment: @joeqwerty: I haven't, but only because she isn't logged in (our shifts only overlap by an hour or two) and I was under the impression that Credential Manager only reflected stores for the currently logged-in user.

Comment: Well it is the same user. The name change doesn't change the user SID, so I'm assuming that any credentials stored for the old username are still valid for the new username but that Samba doesn't recognize the change, maybe because it uses only the username and not the SID.

Comment: I believe Samba does use the SID, but I'm not positive. I'll look into it for part 2 of my question.

Comment: Any solution for that?